# Wrapping a Joomla website into a div

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a pretty straight forward question, in regards to joomla templates.
The end result being : http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php

What I want to do is simple, in a sense, but need to know where to look;
I want to have the entire page wrapped in two divs, all the PHP code, to which class i can define in css and drop in some javascrpt so I can apply page transitions to that div. All of which I know how to do except for where to do it in, the PHP structure of joomla is new to me.

and also, after the first step is accomplished, create a second div after the content that would be dynamically loaded with content from clicked links on the page from within the template, but thats two questions at once lol.

Any ideas on the first part?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use a div to encompass the entire template, do exactly that: wrap the template in a div and give it a custom class or id:

```
<html>
    <head>
        //stuff here
    </head>

    <body>
        //insert the wrapper here
        <div id="wrapper">
            //template structure here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The file you want to edit will likely be named `index.php` located at `public_html/templates/your_template/index.php`.

For some templates, such as those by Yootheme, you will instead want to edit the file at `public_html/templates/your_template/layouts/template.php` (or `/public_html/templates/your_template/styles/current_profile/layouts/template.php` if you're using a profile other than the default).